# " I got selected" =I am or I was selected (specially in british english)

Tags: tense, passive-voice, british-english

"I got selected for a job today."

Apart from "have been", could I replace "got" with "Was" or "Am"?  "I was or I am selected"?

I reckon if I say "I was selected" it will give an impression of past as in two years ago instead of today.

And if I say "I am selected" would it be considered a "state" or "happening of an action as in being selected"?

Answer (score 2):

'I've been selected' denotes the news are fairly recent.
'I was selected' is definitely associated to a past event, unless you use 'today' or a similar adverb in the same sentence to anchor the expression in the present time.

Comment: Without adverb cannot i was selected translate present time and  how about "I am selected". Is it a "state" or  "happening"? And how about "got" is it equivlent to "was" or "am"?

Comment: @ Moderator. How can i follow thIS migrated question which is moved to learners stak exchang?

Comment: 'I got selected' is very informal. In anything except casual conversation you should use _was_ or _have been_. 'I am selected' is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Kate Burning. Could "got" only interpret "was or has been". Could "got" never interpret is,am or are?

Comment: _Got_ is the past tense of _get_, so if you mean to say something in the present tense you should use _get_.

Answer (score 1):

"I have been selected for a job opening today" is correct.

"I got selected" would be an informal usage, more common in American English.

"I am/was selected for a job position today" is also correct usage.
"I am selected" would only be used in the present. For instance, you are at a job interview and the interviewer says, "I'm impressed. This office is where you'll work from tomorrow." You could now say, "So you're telling me I'm selected for the job. Thank you."